# Formatting of GCP cloud logs on mobile

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, winston

I am new to GCP and am running my own ubuntu VM (compute engine) to host a discord bot. I have migrated from heroku where I logged simply with `console.log()`.

I am now using winston to export logs to gcp logger using

```java
const winston = require('winston');

// Imports the Google Cloud client library for Winston
const {LoggingWinston} = require('@google-cloud/logging-winston');

const loggingWinston = new LoggingWinston();

// Create a Winston logger that streams to Cloud Logging
// Logs will be written to: "projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/logs/winston_log"
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
    // Add Cloud Logging
    loggingWinston,
  ],
  exceptionHandlers: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
    // Add Cloud Logging
    loggingWinston,
  ] 
});
```

This works OK on the desktop Web browser, but especially on mobile the logs are not very readable.

Is there a way to perhaps alter the winston settings to make this more readable?

[image: example of logs on mobile]

[image: another example of logs on mobile]